# Escaped JSON in PHP $_COOKIE global

Tags: php, javascript, json

Ok, so I had an odd requirement on a recent project.  In order to get around limitations of our CMS and caching I needed to store and update a JSON object in a cookie after making several AJAX calls.  Later if a user completed a process the information stored in this cookie is used to identify choices made earlier.  The completion can span a few minutes to several weeks, ie. page conversion with virtually no time restriction.

When I went to extract the encoded JSON string from the $_COOKIE global I started getting JSON Syntax errors (actually the bugs cropped up before that point but that is when I started to figure out what was happening).  I was using the built-in JSON.stringify in Javascript to set the cookie value, and json_decode in PHP.

Apparently, PHP will escape the quotes in a string value coming out of $_COOKIE, this caused the JSON syntax error, and the cascade effect after.  I did not see any mention in the PHP JSON functions or $_COOKIE docs.  I ended up doing a preg_replace on the '\' and removing them, and it 'works' now.

That seems to be like a hacky work around.  Was/is there something I am missing? Is there a better way to do this in the future?

when echoing the values and json_last_error():

> $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie_name']; => {\"suffix\":\"general\"...}
>   $cookie = json_decode($cookie, true); => Syntax Error: NULL
>   $cookie = preg_replace('/\\/', "", $cookie); => {"suffix":"general"...}
>   $cookie = json_decode($cookie, true); => No Errors: ARRAY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add the second parameter of json_encode as (some constants need PHP 5.3)

```
json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

also, you'll need `json_decode(stripslashes($json))` since it seems `magic_quotes_gpc` is on

Comment: The encoding of the JSON to a string occurs n Javascript with JSON.stringify, and that is being stored correctly, or at least appears to be when I log it to the console and do an alert.  I mostly use Firefox to develop.

Comment: then use stripslashes on the PHP then, as I showed, or disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in the php.ini, if you can

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the second line in your answer.  And OMG! I can't believe I missed the stripslashes function - frantic bug squashing at 1:30 am is not good for the brain.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably a victim of [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).
Make sure they're turned off.

Comment: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: I just checked my own configuration - running MAMP to develop locally, am using 5.3 PHP.  I changed 5.2 ini to OFF, but phpinfo() still said they were on (magic quotes that is).  I had to dropped the explicit directive to turn them off into my 5.3 ini file to finally get them completely off.  So, even though deprecated, still present and need to be turned off in 5.3 (on by default == com'on man!)